# Liquid: How to delete the first xyz lines of a string

Tags: shopify, liquid, dotliquid

**Hey there!**

I have a string that contains a http response header before the actual result that I want to use.

Like:

```
Vary=Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding=
Keep-Alive=timeout=5, max=100
Connection=Keep-Alive
Content-Length=389
Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date=Fri, 09 Feb 2018 12:09:25 GMT
Server=Apache

<html>
<p>some text</p>
</html>
```

I somehow need to get rid of the response header. What I tried is to use

```
{% assign paragraphs = desc.response | split: '\n' %}
```

and then use somthing like slice to remove the first somewhat 8 lines, but that does not work.

**Is there a way to remove everything before the empty line after Server=Apache?**

The html part I want to use can be modiefied if necessary, for example to prepend some special charakter as limiter or something like that.
However I can not remove the header, since this is part of a 3rd party software (JTL) that - for some reason - puts the header and the body together. I only can edit the result via liquid.

Any help is highly appreciated! Sorry for the (maybe) very simple question, I simply cant figure it out.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue. I solved it by the following trick.

1. Edit the php script, to prepend a delimiter:

   $delimiter = "< !-- split -->"; (remove the space between the  < and the ! )

   $result =  $delimiter . $pre;
2. Split at the delimiter and only take the last part:

   {{ somewhat.field | Split: '< !-- split -->' | Last }}